# How do you access Fixture properties with custom test Action Attributes in nunit?

Tags: c#, nunit-3.0

I have a few custom attributes for writing tests with nunit 2.6.  I recently upgraded (via Nuget) to nunit 3.0.  After the upgrade, all of my Action Attribute failed the build.  I see that `TestDetails` is gone and that is why my attributes will not build.

Reading the documentation here, http://nunit.org/index.php?p=actionAttributes&r=3.0, it looks like they should still work.  The error I get when using the ConsoleActionAttribute provided on that documentation page is:

```
SetUp : System.ArgumentNullException : Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: type
TearDown : System.ArgumentNullException : Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: type
```

Various other attributes throw similar errors like

```
TestFixtureSetUp failed in SomeTestClass
```

What is the proper way to access the Fixture property of a test in the Before/After methods of an Action Attribute?